# Android Fragment necessary

Tags: android

I'm learning how to create apps and I don't really understand the purpose of `Fragment`.

I understand that it's used when using multiple devices but if I'm only using one, do I just leave it alone? Like do I have to make the same adjustments to my fragments file as I do to my `MainActivity` layout file?

Comment: Have a good read : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments are usually used to represent some behavior of the UI. They are used for adapting to multiple screen sizes by combining them, exchanging them, etc.

From the Android developers page:

> You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which
>   has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you
>   can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub
>   activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Its recommended to use them,but you could build your activites with no fragments at all.
In my opinion is a good thing to use them, it will become easier to re use your code or to adapt to more devices on the future. Plus encapsulating your logic.

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) link.
And [here](http://blog.pluralsight.com/android-fragments) is a nice article answering your question.